# how to match and show the last characters of an already regex? It is not the end of the line

Tags: regex

Lets say I have a 100 characters line.
I have a REGEX matching correctly a string of lets say 25 characters in the middle (neither at the beginning nor at the end) of the line.
How can I match the last 5 characters of above 25 match in the middle?

CURRENT REGEX: (dBm)\s+.{7})(\b)

***REAL EXAMPLE:***

Lines:

Tx Output Power (dBm)         -2.31      3.50       0.50      -8.20     -12.20

Rx Optical Power (avg dBm)    -3.72      3.50       0.50     -14.40     -18.39

I am matching the following with my REGEX - *(dBm)\s+.{7})(\b)*

Tx Output Power (**dBm)         -2.31**      3.50       0.50      -8.20     -12.20

Rx Optical Power (**avg dBm)    -3.72**      3.50       0.50     -14.40     -18.39

I am only really interested on:

Tx Output Power (dBm)         **-2.31**      3.50       0.50      -8.20     -12.20

Rx Optical Power (avg dBm)    **-3.72**      3.50       0.50     -14.40     -18.39

Thanks

Comment: Plese, provide your string and regex as a sample.

Comment: (?<=dBm\).........)-\d\.\d\d|(?<=dBm\)....)-\d\.\d\d

Answer (score 0):

Regex

```
.*\([^\)]*\) ([^ ]+).*
```

Result

> -2.31
>
> -3.72
>
> -2.31
>
> -3.72
>
> -2.31
>
> -3.72

Example https://regex101.com/r/S9NO4o/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group:

```
\([^()]*dBm\)\s+(-?\d+(?:)\.\d*)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^()]*` Match 0+ chars other than `(` or `)`
- `dBm\)` Match `dBm)`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `-?\d+(?:)\.\d*` Match optional `-`, then 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bHRZeX/1)

If you want a match only with Java:

```
(?<=\([^()]{0,100}dBm\)\s{0,100})-?\d+(?:)\.\d*\b
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Puhq7Z/1)

In Java with the doubled backslashes:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\([^()]{0,100}dBm\\)\\s{0,100})-?\\d+(?:)\\.\\d*\\b";
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Above answers seem to capture too much information. I did the trick using LOOKBEHIND:

(?<=Tx Output Power \(dBm\)......)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Tx Output Power \(dBm\).......)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Tx Output Power \(dBm\)........)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Tx Output Power \(dBm\).........)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Tx Output Power \(dBm\)..........)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Rx Optical Power \(avg dBm\)...)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Rx Optical Power \(avg dBm\)....)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Rx Optical Power \(avg dBm\).....)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Rx Optical Power \(avg dBm\)......)[-\+\d\.]+|(?<=Rx Optical Power \(avg dBm\).......)[-\+\d\.]+

Comment: BTW, having the spaces removed automatcally in the website, DOES NOT HELP because we cannot duplicated the scenarios

Comment: @JosuHerritarra I have added a shorter pattern for a match only when using Java